# How to syncronize an Excel document in SharePoint with Access

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel, access

I have an Excel Sheet stored in a SharePoint list, but this list will be updated every month. So some employees get the Access file and need to fill in their values, but they should just open the Access file even if the data is new.

They shouldn't link to a new table or something like that. How can I fulfill this in Access?

Answer (score 0):

So if I am understanding correctly, you have
1. an access database in sharepoint 2013
2. that database feeds data to the excel sheet
3. There is a Sharepoint list that is fed from the Excel sheet
?
Is that correct?
And then somehow all the employees need to open that same Access database to input data to drive new data through to Excel and the sharepoint list?

Please clarify.